# How can I sort by date in ms access 2007?

Tags: ms-access, sorting, ms-access-2007, vba

Just want to know how do I sort a text column that shows data in date format mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: Is it a date column or a text column? When you sort, what is wrong with the order? If it is a text column, why is it?

Comment: It is text column displaying date from a sql table.I want to sort it on click of the header.

Comment: If you just have a table view which you are opening with a text field then it will not sort correctly, in this case I think you will need to write a query from this table that converts the text column to a true date value and then sort on that, although if this is a very large SQL table then performance may not be great.

Answer (score 5):

You will first have to convert to a date to get a proper sort. This is a query that converts Datetext to RealDate, and then sorts on that column (field). You can also click the header to choose the sort order.

```
SELECT 
   t.ID, 
   t.Datetext, 
   DateSerial(Mid([Datetext],InStrRev([Datetext],"/")+1),
              Mid([Datetext],1,InStr([Datetext],"/")-1),
              Mid([Datetext],InStr([Datetext],"/")+1,
                 (InStrRev(Datetext,"/")-InStr([Datetext],"/"))-1)) AS RealDate
FROM Table t
Order By 3
```

You can use IIf to avoid errors from null:

```
IIf([Datetext] Is Null,Null,DateSerial(
           Mid([Datetext],InStrRev([Datetext],"/")+1),
           Mid([Datetext],1,InStr([Datetext],"/")-1),
           Mid([Datetext],InStr([Datetext],"/")+1,
              (InStrRev(Datetext,"/")-InStr([Datetext],"/"))-1))) AS RealDate
```

Comment: I do not quite understand how to use this.Do I need to put this query in the onlcick event?

Comment: @user1175126 No, as I mentioned above, if you are just dbl-clicking to open the table then you can't do this, you will need to make a query of the table using the SQL Remou has provided, you can then open this in the same way you would open the table, however the column should sort correctly

Comment: Just paste the sql into the SQL View of the Query Design Window in Access and then change `ID` and `Datetext` to match your set-up. In the line `FROM Table t`, you just need to change `Table` to your table name, `t` is an alias and can be left alone.

Comment: It does sort date.However, I have some doubts.This date column is on a form.I want sorting to be done when user clicks the header.Do I need to run the query when the user clicks the header?

Comment: This is not a query that you run that does something, it is a query that you use instead of your table if you want to sort by date. You cannot use your table anywhere that you need to sort by date. Create a form using the idea in this query rather than a table as the record source for the form. It will be easiest of you create the query first and save it and then base your form on the saved query.

Comment: I would not rely on a string being consistently formatted. If the query is used, the user can right-click the header and choose the sort order.

Comment: @HansUp, Thanks, Order By 3 it is.

Comment: What if Datetext column has null values?I just tried in the query window and it displayes 'error' for nulls.

Comment: If you wish to exclude nulls, you can use a WHERE statement, for example, this will exclude both nulls and zero-length strings `WHERE [Datetext] & ""<>""`, adding Trim will also exclude space-filled strings, or for nulls alone, you can say `WHERE [Datetext] Not Is Null`

Comment: But won't it also exclude other fields also where datetext is null.For instance,if I add a where clause in the above example to exclude vallues where datetext is null,then the entire row for the same will be exclude.I want all the rows to be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

In a comment you said this is a "*text column displaying date from a sql table*".  I'm unsure what you meant by that, but I think the situation could be simpler if you can convert the text column to an actual Date/Time column.

If you're *importing* data from SQL Server into Access, convert those text values when you pull them in to Access.

If the Access table is a *link* to a SQL Server object, create a view in SQL Server which casts the text date column to an Access-compatible date type.  Then on the Access side, replace your existing link with a link to the view.

If you need to edit the date values in Access, not just display and sort them, include both the original text column and the transformed date version in your view.  Do your Access edits to the text column; sort on the Date/Time column.